# How to access the file system using window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL in Typescript? Ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Following the [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html#appendFile) for the File plugin, I can see the paragraph which explains how to append data to a log file. This is the example code:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function (dirEntry) {
    ...
}, onErrorLoadFs);
```

However I get an error

> Property 'resolveLocalFileSytemURL' does not exist on type 'Window'.

Does anyone know why this would happen? Are there alternative ways to append to a file using this plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the files of a directory use `listDir` -
 https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/:

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

constructor(private file: File) { }

...

this.file.listDir('file:///', this.file.dataDirectory)
    .then(_ => console.log('Directory exists'))
    .catch(err => console.log('Directory doesnt exist'));
```

Comment: I ended up using         **(<any>window)**.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(this.file.dataDirectory, function (directoryEntry) {   ...  } , because I needed to get the DirectoryEntry file. With your suggestion I would get array of entries: [Entry], so I didn't follow that road, but I suppose it could be done. Thank you for the suggestion, though :)

Comment: interesting when I ran into this problem I thought I tried that with `<any>window` ...well good job...and np